# django's form is not saved in store

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a quiz form and when I want to save the answer the model does not store its question. I want to validate the form and save it when `if form.is_valid ()`: I remove it and instead of **AnswerForm** I use the direct **Answer** model then it saves but not so. How to change it so that I can validate it and save it with the help of the form?

my code ->

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Question(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer_question=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    
class Answer(models.Model):
    questin=models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions")
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.questin)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Question,Answer

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Question
        fields="__all__"



class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

   
    class Meta:
        model=Answer
        fields="__all__"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import QuestionForm,AnswerForm
from .models import Question,Answer
import random
from django.forms import modelformset_factory



def home(request):
    form=QuestionForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, "question/base.html", {"form":form})

def ans(request):
    questions=Question.objects.all()
    form=AnswerForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            qu=request.POST["i_id"]
            question_id=int(qu)
            answ=AnswerForm(questin=question_id,answer=request.POST["answer"])
            answ.save()
            
            
            
    return render(request, "question/ans.html", {"form":form, "questions":questions})
```

ans.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>question</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        {% for i in questions %}
        <form method="POST" required>
            
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            
                
                {{i}}
                <input type="hidden" name="i_id" value="{{ i.id }}"/>
                {% for a in form.answer %}
                    {{a}}
                    
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" name="sub">
           
        </form>
        
        {% endfor %}
        
        
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you not using form.save()?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat don't save